# to get individual rows of the list in a single data frame Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list created after perforing basic filter in a WHILE loop. now I want each of my list ros in a single DataFrame That I can access outside the loop.

the code I have is

```
filePath = "pinToBall_Bump.csv"

with open(filePath, 'r') as inpFile:
    line = inpFile.readline()
    while line:
        # print(line)
        filter1 = re.sub(r'^[io_]+', "", line)
        filter2 = re.sub(r'^[gddr6_]+', "", filter1)
        filterList = filter2.split(",")
        print(filterList)
        line = inpFile.readline()
```

Comment: FYI you can write `for line in inpFile:` to loop over the lines, instead of calling `readline()` twice and testing it.

Comment: now my code looks like
with open(filePath, 'r') as inpFile:
    for line in inpFile:
        # print(line)
        filter1 = re.sub(r'^[io_]+', "", line)
        filter2 = re.sub(r'^[gddr6_]+', "", filter1)
        allUpper = filter2.upper()
        print(allUpper)

how can I now get the allUpper string type in a single dataframe which I can access as a whole set outside of the for loop

Comment: See the question I linked to above. It shows how to add a list as a row to a pandas dataframe.